# How to await inside NodeJS request?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

in NodeJS I have the following code inside a function:

```js
var request = require('request-promise');

exports.quotetest = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {


// ... code ...

await request(options, function (error, response, body) {

          const jsondata =  JSON.parse(body).response;
          

          firestore.collection('Partite').doc('Serie A').update({
            [m]  : {"home":jsondata[0].bookmakers[0]  }

        });


    })
}
```

And it gives me the following error: `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'bookmakers')`. I think because when I update Firestore `jsondata` isn't ready yet. How could I wait for jsondata to be ready? If I try `const jsondata =  await JSON.parse(body).response;` I receive the following error: `SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules`

Comment: Functions that use callback functions can’t be awaited. You are passing a callback to `request`

Comment: can you look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55240125/15774176), is it helpful?

Answer (score -1):

If I try `const jsondata =  await JSON.parse(body).response;` I receive the following error:

> SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules**

This does not work as it clearly states await is valid in async function, which means your `JSON.parse(....)` needs to be async which is not the case.

Coming to your problem: you need to give a slight delay between your function call and when response is sent Try to call the below function which gives a delay:

```
async function hangOn() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 100));
}
```

Call this function between your function call to create json data and your response like this:

```
await hangOn()
```

I recently ran into similar problem which can be referred from below thread:
[Call async function via PUT API call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73446423/call-async-function-via-put-api-call)